# PHP backend, Java front end. Is this possible?

Tags: java, php, communication

my question is pretty simple: can PHP and Java communicate, while PHP being the backend, aka server side script?

i know [this php-java-bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/how_it_works.php) exists but it says how it works:

*"A PHP front end is contained in, or associated with, a Java back end."*

and i want the other way around.

EDIT:
**Is it possible to establish a communication between Java applet(front end) and PHP(backend)?**

Comment: Why? What's the purpose?

Comment: Have you considered a PHP service-based architecture? Where you have, what I assume are Java controllers calling PHP RestFul (or SOAP-based) services?

Comment: I am also really interested to know why would you need that?

Comment: I'm just researching what's available to me, but I want a Java applet(a chat client) to communicate with a PHP script on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about servlets, Java Front end will be servlet, Then Yes. Servlet will communicate through POST/GET to the backend.

Comment: No, not servlets.I correct the question than: is it possible to establish a communication between java applet(front end) and PHP(backend)?

Comment: Java Applet, Java Servlet, no different. As long as the communicate is through URL request, then it is do-able. URL request can be POST or GET

Comment: Similar idea to javascript Ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

You could build your java program in such a way that it will do all of its initialization based on the command line arguments.  This way you can use the simple `exec` call from php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php is a reference on how its used. It will return the results from the command line.  So your java program could use `System.out.print`

Comment: This is obviously a very hackish way to do communication.  But it could be done!  without all the library and setup required.  But if there needed to be more extensive communication besides command line arguments, then this is no good.

Comment: Ohh java applet... i thought you said Java and Php, i do not think your original question had Java Applet.. neeto